# Is there a way to make lambda call a definition using if condition?

Tags: python

I am doing an optimization problem and I'm trying to define a constraint using lambda and def.

Essentially what I want to do is:

```
lambda x: add_2 if no_added == 2
```

add_2 is the definition I want to call:

```
def add_2(x):
    lc2 = x[36]-0.02
    return lc2
```

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Comment: `lambda x: add_2(x) if no_added == 2 else None`?

Comment: What should your lambda function return if `no_added` is not 2?

Comment: @Netwave why not write an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I was doing it :)

Comment: I'm using lambda in my constraint line and I want the constraint to be ignored if the condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the funtion and make a default `else` block:

```
lambda x: add_2(x) if no_added == 2 else None
```

Return other value if None do not work for you.
Anyway, you can handle this **inside** the function:

```
def add_2(x, no_added):
    if no_added == 2:
        return x[36]-0.02
    return None
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, just saying, I did not downvoted your answer.